# Using a pointer to an array to fill dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want to pass an array to a constructor and use its elements to fill in a dynamic array. However, I cannot understand how to go about using this array in the constructor.

I have made a function that returns a pointer to this array but I cannot use it inside the constructor for the object I am trying to create.

```
struct PCB
{
   private:
   int * ptr;
   public:
   PCB(int * array)
   {
      ptr=new int[3];
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
         *(ptr+i)=*(array+i);
      }
   }
};

int * returnPtr()
{
   int blockArr[]={21,2,3};
   return blockArr;
}

int main()
{
   PCB * pcb=new PCB(returnPtr());
}
```

This code gives me a "segmentation fault" error using visual studio code. I simply want to be able to copy the elements of the array into the dynamic array. Where have I messed up?

Comment: The problem is that the memory of the array is freed after the execution of the function returnPtr.

Comment: Why are you using low level pointers? Why not just use `std::vector` and `std::array`?

Answer (score 1):

You declared blockArr as a local memory, and it will be deleted once you get out of returnPtr function.
allocate byteArr as just as you allocated ptr.

```
int blockArr = new int[3];
```

Comment: blockArr was declared as local memory, no static. If were static there were no problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
struct PCB
{
   private:
   int * ptr;
   public:
   PCB(int * array)
   {
      ptr=new int[3];
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
         *(ptr+i)=*(array+i);
      }
   }
};

int main()
{
   int blockArr[]={21,2,3};
   PCB * pcb=new PCB(blockArr);
}
```

It should fix the "segmentation fault". 
And remember create a destructor.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. Is it possible to achieve this without getting rid of the function "returnPtr"?

Comment: well, there several approaches, one is using `static int blockArr[]={21,2,3};`, so the memory will remain as long as the program do

Comment: other way is declare the array in the global scope, but I don't like it that way